# Bernoulli Conjecture on $B_{2^n}$

Tags: number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

So in a recent question I was trying to prove that $2^n-1$ will never be a Carmichael number ([Can a Mersenne number ever be a Carmichael number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880896/can-a-mersenne-number-ever-be-a-carmichael-number)), I was going to prove it true as long as  a certain property about Bernoulli numbers occured. (I know realized I made a huge mistake, but anyway...)

The property I noticed was that the denominators of $B_{2^n}$ are the product of consecutive Fermat primes. (With $2^0+1 = 2$ included)

Ex: Denominators tested:

- $6 = 2*3$
- $30 = 2*3*5$
- $510 = 2*3*5*17$
- $131070 = 2*3*5*17*257$

Maybe even more specifically: the denominator of $B_{2^n}$ is the product of consecutive Fermat primes less than or equal to $2^n+1$.

Comment: [Von Staudt-Clausen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem)

Comment: perhaps not true with carmichael numbers as n?