# Can $n^2-1$ be a Carmichael number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, carmichael-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

> Can $n^2-1$ be a Carmichael number ?

Some thoughts :

- n must be even, since $n^2-1$ must be odd.
- Every prime factor $p\mid n^2-1$ must satisfy $p-1\mid n^2-2$. This rules out prime factors of the forms $3k+1,4k+1,5k+1$
- Neither $n-1$ nor $n+1$ can be prime. In the first case, we have $n-2\mid n^2-2$ , implying $n-2\mid 2$ , hence $n-2\le 2$. In the second case , we have $n\mid n^2-2$ , hence $n\mid 2$, hence $n\le 2$. But the smallest Carmichael number is $561$, hence $n$ must at least be $24$.
- Brute force reveals that for $n\le 10^9$, there is no Carmichael number of this form.

Comment: For the case $n=2^k$ there are some posts, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880896/can-a-mersenne-number-ever-be-a-carmichael-number), but I don't know how helpful they are. You checked until $2^{3500}-1$ several years ago. November $5$ of $2015$, to be precise.

Comment: I extended my search limit to $10^{10}$

Comment: A thought toward a partial  solution: Having no prime factors of the form $3k+1$ means all prime factors are either $3$ or of the form $6k-1$. Setting aside the possibility of $3$ for the moment, if $n-1$ and $n+1$ have only factors of the form $6k-1$, then they themselves are of the form $6m\pm 1$. This would require that $n-1$ has an odd number of prime factors, and $n+1$ has an even number of prime factors.

Comment: Antoher thought: $n^2-1$ has to be a pseudo-prime to base $2$, since all Carmichael numbers fulfill this condition.